# Simple Koa middleware breaking application

Tags: node.js, koa

I downloaded a great [react+redux starter kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit) that includes a very simple Koa server.  I want to add an extremely simple middleware to this Koa server that just logs "Hello".  This is what I've added to the server/main.js at line 30

```
app.use(function *(next){
  console.log("Hello")
  yield next;
});
```

However, when I add this I get a "Not Found" page in the browser.  As soon as I take it away, everything works great again!  I'm very confused as to where I'm going wrong.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After much searching I finally fixed it.  It turns out Koa is updating their middleware.  To see the difference, check [koa-convert](https://github.com/koajs/convert) out, it has some examples.  Here is my updated middleware

```
app.use((ctx, next) => {
  console.log("WOOO");
  return next();
});
```